# ActiveRecord associations outside Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I am using active_record to connect to a database. I am working in plain ruby and not rails. I can connect to the database fine and do all the stuff except associations.

Can I do something like this?

```
    class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :orders        
    end
```

When I do this I get an error warning in RubyMine saying, it can't find a Rails Model called `order` even though I have an`Order` class as above. Since I am not in rails I wonder whether it's possible to do so in plain ruby?

Comment: You have to do `class Person < ActiveRecord::Base end`

Comment: and probably `require 'rubygems'` and `require 'active_record'` as well.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant i think he have already done this things.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely running into the need to tell ruby where to find your files. Rails using autoloading to accomplish this, but you'll need to tell the Person class where to find the order class.

```
require "./order"
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :orders
end
```